# Parse log level with a regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have text that I want to parse. The `log` level for example:

```
This is simple [fail] text
```

So in this case I want to take `[fail]`, so I do it with `\[.*?\]`.

Now in case my `log` level is with this format:
`|fail|` I want to be able to parse it as well, so I try to add this:

```
\[.*?\]|.*?\|
```

But in case my text is `This is simple |fail| text`, the match is only `fail|`.

Comment: you forgot to escape the first pipe

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That's an "or" - he forgot the first pipe completely :D

Comment: Unrelated: If you want to parse logs efficiently, you shouldn't scatter the level somewhere in the line. It's much easier to have a fixed position for that. Then you can nevermind the delimiters.

Comment: What do you mean fixed position ?>

Comment: He means making sure that `[something]` always starts at the Nth character

Comment: i am reading process output and this [something] comes in different locations... (strange i know)

Comment: So, you have no control over the format. OK. That's too bad but well, it is what it is. The answer to the question, though is use `\[.*?\]|\|.*?\|`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?:(\[)|(\|)).*?(?(1)]|\|)
```

See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%5C%5B%29%7C%28%5C%7C%29%29.*%3F%28%3F%281%29%5D%7C%5C%7C%29&i=This%20is%20simple%20%5Bfail%5D%20text%0D%0AThis%20is%20simple%20%7Cfail%7C%20text). Or, only matching `fail`:

```
(?<=(?:(\[)|(\|))).*?(?=(?(1)]|\|))
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3F%3A%28%5C%5B%29%7C%28%5C%7C%29%29%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%28%3F%281%29%5D%7C%5C%7C%29%29&i=This%20is%20simple%20%5Bfail%5D%20text%0D%0AThis%20is%20simple%20%7Cfail%7C%20text).

**Regex details**

- `(?:(\[)|(\|))` - either  `[` (captured into Group 1) or `|` (captured into Group 2)
- `.*?` - any zero or more characters other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?(1)]|\|)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 was matched (`[`), then match `]`, else, match `|`.

In the second pattern, the left- and right-hand boundaries are enclosed into non-consuming lookarounds.